# launchd StartCalendarInterval not working reliably

Tags: macos, launchd

I have several tasks that I run from launchd using StartCalendar interval.

Under Yosemite these do not necessarily run. (Under Mavericks and earlier they did run)

How do I see what launchd is doing and thinks should happen, how can I get launchd to log what happens(The tasks themselves write to logs but if they don't run I obviously get nothing)

For example I have this task which is due off at 1212 and 1412 and 2039 and on at 0601. The log gives all at the same time

```
2014-11-08 15:29:56.082 tdtool_mwb[9383:329594] Turning off device 3, Other
2014-11-08 15:29:56.684 tdtool_mwb[9387:329601] Turning on device 3, Other
2014-11-08 22:32:18.563 tdtool_mwb[14594:523323] Turning off device 3, Other
2014-11-09 18:16:52.844 tdtool_mwb[21630:891263] Turning on device 3, Other
2014-11-09 18:16:52.844 tdtool_mwb[21626:891252] Turning off device 3, Other
2014-11-09 20:42:37.353 tdtool_mwb[23789:973903] Turning off device 3, Other
```

My machine does turn at 0600 and I was logged in at midday to 2100 on both days.

Note I have other scripts that have the same issue it is not just something with tdtool_mwb (or even if it was how do I debug this)

If I reboot then they run correctly for a day or two.

If the machine is running and not sleeping then also seems OK but if it sleeps then it fails.

Comment: Just some notes to save people encountering this issue some time:
1) Today's 10.10.1 update does not fix this problem. 
2) Recreating the tasks does not seem to help. 
3) I have not found a way to turn on additional logging, the previous logging feature appears to have been disabled. I'd be curious to hear from anyone who has StartCalendarInterval working, since I'm curious whether a clean install helps.

Comment: Someone over at Google Groups posted this as a bug to Apple, and it was closed as a duplicate: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/uk.comp.sys.mac/obAf_y9irVk/UkDW9Z0pxP4J

Comment: Seems to be fixed in OS X 10.10.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug introduced in 10.10.0 as mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/uk.comp.sys.mac/obAf_y9irVk/UkDW9Z0pxP4J)

It seems to have been fixed in 10.10.3