# How to schedule run of .command file (bash)?

Tags: macos, terminal, calendar, bash

I have a bash script (saved as `myfilename.command`) and would like to schedule its run. I've tried to use Calendar event for this (which works fine with Automator scripts), but I get the following error -

> “myfilename.command” can’t be opened because CoreServicesUIAgent is
>   not allowed to open documents in Terminal.

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways and I think the first step is to make the .command file just a shell script.

Given you comment re automator I would suggest the easiest way is to create an automator/applescript that calls this shell script. This then can be called by calendar

Other ways are using non GUI tools and call the shell script from a cron or launchd entry

Comment: What does "... but not launchd does not work in Yosemite" mean here?

Comment: An extra negation + see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/155833/launchd-startcalendarinterval-not-working-reliably